# MP4 tags: Please suggest best place for Artist and Title for BACKGROUND music

Tags: metadata, mp4

Sorry, I’m not sure whether this is a topic for Stack Overflow, but I give it a try.

In MP4 Metadata, what is the best place to store Artist and Title of **Background** music ?
It is obvious that for normal music videos, one would use the standard Artist and Title tags, but I’m talking about background music for self-made videos, e.g. if I have a video of my grandson’s judo-training, and I use a renderer to add an extra audiotrack, e.g. half-a-minute of ‘Help’ by The Beatles, or some own piano or guitarmusic, I want to document that music, but not in the standard tags, because there are quite a few viewers that only show the standard tags for Artist and Title (and sort on them), but they then do not show the normal filename :-(

Thanks for any suggestion.

P.S. Just for info, and it is not relevant for my question, but for the time being I use **Mp3tag.exe** (yes, it works very easy for MP4 files as well) to write the Artist and Title info and I use **jsmediatags** to read the tags, and it’s an awesome program, so thank you António Afonso

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any tag specially designed for this purpose.  The best bet would probably be to add it as another line in the `Description`.

For example

> Video of my grandson Johnny on June 22, 1984, at the Cobra Kai studio in Encino
>
> Background music is "Help" by The Beatles

Comment: thanks, and yes, if I can't think of another possibility, I'll probably go for the description.